# How set a subdomain const in ionic from the ionic storage?

Tags: angular, promise, ionic3, storage

I'm building an app where users have to login on a certain subdomain. That's different for every user. So on the login page the user logged in whit subdomain, username and password. Before doing api calls I have to save the subdomain in the ionic storage. That's no problem but how I'll use that subdomain as a const in my api service because it's a async it doen't give the value right away.

This is my function in the service

```
startFunction(entry) {
    this.storage.get('subdomain').then(
        result => {
            return this.http.post(result + this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(entry), { headers: HEADER.headers}
            );
        }
    )

}
```

and this my page component

```
otherFunction(){
    this.GetApi.startFunction(entry).subscribe(
    result => {
        console.log(result)
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

But this gives an error `cannot subscribe to undefined`, how to use the async storage value in a promise/observable. Best would be a sort of const that I can use for every function in the api service.

Comment: So `postData` is `startFunction`?

Comment: my bad, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage a the `HttpInterceptor` here to avoid getting the subdomain for all http-request. HttpInterceptor is great! :D

So what you could do, create an interceptor, as it says in your question you set the subdomain before making any http-request, so assumingly there is always a subdomain when you are making a http request.

Also I see that you are setting headers. If the headers are same for all, you can also do that in the interceptor. I'm not including it here though.

So this is how your interceptor could look like:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const obs = Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('subdomain'));
      return obs.flatMap(data => {
        console.log(data); // here should be your subdomain
        // add your subdomain, and the rest of the url
        const apiReq = req.clone({ url: `${data}${req.url}` });
        return next.handle(apiReq);

    })
  }
}
```

This means then, that in your request, ignore the subdomain, and just add the part of the latter url, since we are adding the subdomain in the interceptor:

```ts
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, entry, { headers: HEADER.headers}
```

Here's a dummy example where I just set the data in the storage in the interceptor, you would do that where you are currently doing.

*Note, you don't need to stringify the payload.*

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-p5bczb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That’s were I am looking for thanx!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it was suitable for you! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the promise from the `startFunction`:

```
startFunction(entry) {
    return this.storage.get('subdomain').then(result => {
//  ^^^^^^
        return this.http.post(result + this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(entry), { headers: HEADER.headers};
    });
}
```

and then use `then` instead of `subscribe`:

```
otherFunction(){
    this.GetApi.startFunction(entry).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanx that’s working, but leaves me to the question is there no smarter way to do this? With a const ore something reusable?

Comment: You could probably store the `this.storage.get('subdomain')` promise in a constant to reuse it, but honestly I don't know enough about ionic or your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi answer is correct. But you need to subscribe after the resolve of the promise, because your promise returns an observable:

```
startFunction(entry) {
    return this.storage
               .get('subdomain')
               .then(result => this.http.post(result + this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(entry), { headers: HEADER.headers});
}
```

And:

```
otherFunction(){
    this.GetApi.startFunction(entry)
               .then( observable$ => observable$.subscribe( result => 
    {
        console.log(result)
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    }))
}
```

Comment: Maybe `startFunction().then(promiseFromObservable).then(console.log, console.error)`?